# Modular Group Arithmetic with Primes

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need help understanding what this means:
Working in sets $\mathbf Z_N^* = \{a \in \{0,1,...,N-1\} : gcd(a,N) = 1\}$

If I have a prime $p$ then I claim there is a value $k$ such that
$g^x = g^\left(x\mod k\right) (\mod p) $ for all x
How do I find $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Assuming $g \not \equiv 0 \mod p$, there is a smallest $k$ such that $g^k\equiv 1 \mod p$. This is the $k$ you want. If you show more work, I can give a more detailed hint but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Is the value of $k$ dependent on $g$ ? The two things I can think of are either the order of $g$ or just the size of the group $Z_N^*$.

Comment: It depends on $g$. For example if $g=1$, $k=1$. For other $g$, $k$ could be different. However, there is a $k$ that is valid for all $g$ but for a specific $g$ a smaller $k$ may suffice. Your answer is correct: $k$ must be the order of $g$ if you want the smallest $k$ for a given $g$. If you want a $k$ that is independent of $g$ then you need the order of the group.

Comment: In the case where we use the order of the group: say for $Z_11^* = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ we have $|Z_11^*| = 10$

and I try $g^21 = g^21 mod 10 (mod 11)$ 

is it because doing $g^21 mod 11$ is equivalent to $g^\left(21 mod 10\right) mod 11$?

Comment: yes. Then $g^5 \equiv g^{15}\equiv g^{25} \mod 11$. This follows from Fermat's Little theorem.

Comment: Ah! I understand now, Thank you!

Comment: Cool! I really wanted you to *see* the answer on your own. Which is why I was reluctant to give all the details.